# Vim: after scrolling up using the mouse, the file content is not shown, but the xterm terminal content

Tags: vim

Im getting this sometimes when i scroll up the files im editing.

http://postimage.org/image/ajhrqm3ox/

As you can see the part above is not the file im editing, but the content of the terminal before running vim..:).

Comment: Scrolling how? With the mouse wheel?  `set mouse=a`

Comment: @Michael, you should make it an answer.

Comment: @Michael yes, with the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are attempting to scroll with the mouse wheel and the terminal is capturing it and scrolling back in its own buffer, enable mouse mode, enable the mouse:

```
set mouse=a
```

See `:help mouse` for an explanation of the mouse modes possible, and note that this will also enable positioning Vim's cursor with the mouse, making visual selections, and other expected mouse behaviors.